# jQuery slider - slide: function (event, ui) in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I have a simple code with 2 (or more) jQuery sliders:

HTML:

```
<label for="ST">ST:</label>
<input type="text" id="ST" value="10">
<div id="slider-ST"></div>        

<label for="DX">DX:</label>
<input type="text" id="DX" value="10">
<div id="slider-DX"></div>
```

and JS:

```
$function(){    
$( "#slider-ST" ).slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  value: 10,

  slide: function (event, ui) {sliderChange(ui,"#ST");}
});


$( "#slider-DX" ).slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  value: 10,

  slide: function (event, ui) {sliderChange(ui,"#DX");}
});

function sliderChange(t, disp)
{
   $(disp).val(t.value);
};
}
```

It works perfectly well.

Now, I want to make it nicer and I would like to call these functions in a for loop:

```
$function(){
var ID_Inp = ["#slider-ST", "#slider-DX"];    
var ID_Sli = ["#ST", "#DX"];     
var i;
for (i=0;i<ID_Inp.length;i++)
{
  $(ID_Inp[i]).slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  min: 1,
  max: 18,
  value: 10,

  slide: function (event, ui) {sliderChange(ui,ID_Sli[i]);}
  });
};
function sliderChange(t, disp)
{
   $(disp).val(t.value);
};
}
```

Simplified code also available at jsfiddle:

[working](https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/10337/)

[not working (using for loop)](https://jsfiddle.net/jjjuLcoq/1/)

And what happens is, that *i* is set to 2 after changing the slider's value and obviously function sliderChange doesn't work properly (*ID_Sli[i]* is *undefined*).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a JSFiddle that is working for you, this code does not seem to work !!

Comment: Updated the code with simple jsfiddle examples.

Comment: slide: function( event, ui ) {    alert ('#' + ID_Sli[i]); },  printing the value of ID_Sli[i] inside the function of slider, it prints #undefined, it means the Name arrays are not accessible from inside function. Hence it is not able to update the Input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need to use a for loop in this situation, this could be simplified. Expanding on Govind's idea, if you encapsulate the Sliders & Inputs into individual Div's:

```
<div id="bedsSection">
    <input type="text" id="amountbeds">
    <div id="slider-range-max-beds"></div>
</div>
```

Following this, using the same event, you could then query the parent to find the relevant input. Update accordingly.

```
$( "#slider-range-max-beds, #slider-range-max-cars" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      value: 2,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
                var input = $(this).parent().find("input");
                input.val( ui.value );

            //Could also be written as $(this).parent().find("input").val(ui.value); 
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop is not good option for this , I think you need to do like following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#slider-range-max-cars,#slider-range-max-beds").slider({
      range: "max",
      value: 2,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amountcars").val($("#slider-range-max-cars").slider("value"));
        $("#amountbeds").val($("#slider-range-max-beds").slider("value"));
      }
    });
    $("#amountcars").val($("#slider-range-max-cars").slider("value"));
    $("#amountbeds").val($("#slider-range-max-beds").slider("value"));
  });
</script>

<body>
  <label for="beds">Minimum number of bedrooms:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amountbeds">
  <div id="slider-range-max-beds"></div>

  <p>
    <label for="cars">Minimum number of cars:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amountcars">
    <div id="slider-range-max-cars"></div>
    <div id="debug">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For more information read [documention](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical)

Answer (score 0):

Dear Ramakanth,

Thank you for your answers. Thanks to those, I compiled the code that works well (and kind-of uses *for*, so I don't have to manually type in IDs in initialization phase):

```
<div class="params">      
<div id="STSection">
<label for="ST">Strength:</label>
<input type="text" id="ST" value="10">
<div id="slider-ST" style="width:300px;"></div>        
</div>
<div id="DXSection">
<label for="DX">Dexterity:</label>
<input type="text" id="DX" value="11">
<div id="slider-DX" style="width:300px;"></div>        
</div>
```

and JS:

```
$('.params div').each(function() {
        $(this).find("div").slider({
        value: $(this).find("input").val(),
        orientation: "horizontal",
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).parent().find("input").val(ui.value);
           }
        });
    });
```

The most important part for me to understand was how to work with *.each()* that are embedded into div sections. Then obviously to use *parent()* and *find()*. Those are really helpful!

Thank you!